# how to read the java DataOutputStream data in C# application

Tags: java, c#

i have tried to pass the "Hello Server" message from java code to dot net code but  i could not able to read that message.How can i read the message from dot net.

JAVA:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{  
try
{      
Socket s=new Socket("192.168.1.100",6666);  
DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());  
dout.writeUTF("Hello Server");  
dout.flush();  
dout.close();  
s.close();  
}
catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.println(e);
}  
}
```

Dot Net:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {  
        System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener serverSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener(6666);
        int requestCount = 0;
        TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
        serverSocket.Start();
        Console.WriteLine(" » Server Started");
        clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
        Console.WriteLine(" » Accept connection from client");
        requestCount = 0;
    try
    {
        var reader = new BinaryReader(clientSocket.GetStream());
        var value = reader.ReadChar(); 
        Console.WriteLine(" » " + value);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }

    clientSocket.Close();
    serverSocket.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(" » exit");

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I guess `reader.ReadChar()` reads at most 1 character. Do you see that printed or is something else happening?

Comment: It does not print anything so i have changed it to reader.ReadString() but it still does not print anything.

Comment: can someone please help me on this..

Answer (score -1):

I have found out the solution,

```
  string s = string.Empty, NewLine = string.Empty; ;
                    System.IO.StreamReader MyStreamReader=new System.IO.StreamReader(clientSocket.GetStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                    while((NewLine=MyStreamReader.ReadLine())!=null)
                        s+=NewLine+"\r\n";
                    MyStreamReader.Close();
```

Comment: It would be easier to use the `ReadToEnd()` method of the `StreamBuffer` class